# SSIS Email Request Delivery Receipt

Tags: ssis, taskfactory

Is there any way to request Delivery Receipt or Read Receipt from the SSIS Email Task or from the Task Factory Email Task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a third-party product like [CozyRoc](https://www.cozyroc.com/products).